# How to convert a sparse matrix to a list of sparse arrays?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, sparse-arrays

I have a matrix stored as a `SparseArray`. How can I convert it to a `List` of its rows, where each row is stored as a `SparseArray`?

Note that the matrix is huge, so the conversion should use as little memory as possible (the lower bound being the memory of the final `List` object).

Comment: Like `Table[SparseArray[Band[{1, 1}] -> 1, {4, 4}][[k]], {k, 4}]`?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, that is the final representation I want. How do I convert an input sparse matrix to this form?

Comment: Well, you could replace the `SparseArray[]` in my snippet with yours, for example.

Comment: @J.M. This works and gives the result that I want. However, for some reason it is very slow for me. Maybe there is a faster way?

Comment: Can you give a (minimal?) example of a sparse matrix where this goes slow?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`List @@ s` will do the trick:

```
s = 1000000 // RandomInteger[{1, 1000000}, {#, 2}] -> RandomReal[1, #]& // SparseArray;

s // Head
(* SparseArray *)

s // Dimensions
(* {1000000, 1000000} *)

l = List @@ s;

l // Head
(* List *)

l // Dimensions
(* {1000000, 1000000} *)

l // First // Head
(* SparseArray *)

Take[l, 4]
```

[image: sparse array screenshot]

**Why Does This Work?**

Commentators observe that replacing the head of the (apparent) `FullForm` of a `SparseArray` ought to produce a nonsensical result.  Why, then, does this work?

Despite appearances, a `SparseArray` is an atom:

```
SparseArray[Range[10]] // AtomQ
(* True *)
```

The full-form is therefore synthetic.  Any operations that operate upon the (notionally non-existent) subparts of these atoms are implemented as special definitions.  The [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) strongly implies that a `SparseArray` is meant to act virtually interchangeably with a regular `List`.

The *Details* section gives explicit examples where the parts of a multidimensional sparse array themselves appear as sparse arrays to operations like `Map`, `Part`, `Listable`, etc.  In light of this, it stands to reason that replacing the notional head of a multidimensional sparse array with `List` would result in a list of sparse arrays.  It is likely that the implementation has explicit code to handle this case.

I cannot point to a definitive statement in the documentation that guarantees the behaviour of `List @@ s`.  But I would argue that it is so strongly implied that it would be a regression if it were changed in some future release.

Comment: Simple and fast!

Comment: Brilliant, but I don't understand why doest it work considering what is the  `FullForm` of a `SparseArray`. Can you comment on the rationale behind?

Comment: Actually I didn't understand either, I was just happy it worked. I second @rhermans request for further explanation.

Comment: @rhermans I added the section _Why Does This Work?_

Answer (score 3):

Easy to do with `Map`.

This generates a random sparse matrix(array):

```
{m, n} = {1000, 2000};
pairs = Flatten[
   Outer[List, RandomInteger[{1, m}, Floor[0.7 m]], 
    RandomInteger[{1, n}, Floor[0.7 n]]], 1];
smat = SparseArray[
  Thread[pairs -> RandomReal[{0, 1}, Length[pairs]]], {m, n}]
```

[image]

Get the rows:

```
vecs = Map[# &, smat];
```

Verify it is all sparse arrays:

```
Shallow[Head /@ vecs]

(* Out[170]//Shallow= {SparseArray, SparseArray, SparseArray, \
SparseArray, SparseArray, SparseArray, SparseArray, SparseArray, \
SparseArray, SparseArray, <<990>>} *)
```

Here is some profiling code:

Profiling code:

```
memOld = MemoryInUse[];
timeOld = Date[];
vecs = Map[# &, smat];
memNew = MemoryInUse[];
timeNew = Date[];

(memNew - memOld)
(memNew - memOld)/memOld // N
timeNew - timeOld  

(* 12172576

   0.170369

  {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.021384} *)
```

(I got the output on a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7 MacBook Pro laptop with Mathematica 10.3.2.)

Comment: Hah, I'd done it as `Identity /@ smat` myself, but I wasn't sure if it was faster or slower than `Table[]`.

Comment: I did some profiling: `Identity /@ smat` does not seem faster than `#& /@ smat` and it seems to be 10-20% less memory consuming.  Of course the comparison should be done on a collection of sparse matrices with different sizes and densities.

Answer (score 2):

> @WReach has provided the ultimate answer. Consider this an extended comment about the performance of [`ArrayRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayRules.html)

---

A large [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html)

```
sa = SparseArray[
   Table[
    RandomInteger[{1, 99999}, 2] -> RandomReal[1]
    , 9999]
   ];
```

An example with [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) that takes some time even for a subset of the rows (some list will be empty).

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[Table[sa[[k]], {k, 9999}]]
(* 2.68629 *)
```

But **if** you can get away with [`ArrayRules`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayRules.html) instead of [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html)

```
First@AbsoluteTiming[GatherBy[Most@ArrayRules[sa], First@*First]]
(* 0.0172612 *)
```

Comment: With the `Table` form dont'you extract only the first 9999 rows?

Comment: Yes, in the `Table` form you are missing most rows, that's why the timing is so small I think.

Comment: not a fair timing comparison unless you add the code to reconstruct the individual sparse arrays.

Comment: Yes, this of not for benchmark, times here are only to show that what is almost impossibly slow even for a subsection of a `SparseArray`  becomes trivial with `ArrayRules` for the whole set. This may or may not be of use to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If `m` contains your `SparseArray`

```
m = SparseArray[{{1, 2} -> a, {3, 2} -> b, {3, 3} -> c}];
```

[image]

then the following will return its list of sparse array rows.

```
m[[#]] & /@ Range[First@Dimensions@m]
```

[image]

Hope this helps.